# Google analytics e-commerce does not register transactions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce application on ASP.NET MVC + Vue.JS. Right now I am trying locally send data to google analytics but it does not catch any transactions. It only registers new active user.

I created an account on analytics where I enabled E-commerce and received Tracking ID. Right now I included java script that should send some test data to google analytics while the page is loaded. The code is below.

```
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'my Tracking id', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');   // Load the ecommerce plug-in.

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required
        'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name
        'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total
        'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping
        'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax
    });

    // addItem should be called for every item in the shopping cart.
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required
        'name': 'T-Shirt',                // Product name. Required
        'sku': 'DD44',       // SKU/code
        'category': 'Green Medium',       // Category or variation
        'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price
        'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send')
```

Can you please give me some suggestions why this is not working?

Comment: Hi, open browser webTools. Change to "network" tab and search for all requests with "collect" in url. If everything is okey i guess there should be 2 requests. First for pageview and second one including ecommerce data. Check this at the beginning. Other useful tool for debugging GA is chrome extension called "Google Analytics Debugger" (highly recommended to debugging ecommerce etc.)

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that I had to wait until next day.